Why is dimethylamine more basic in aqueous solution than trimethylamine?
I expected trimethylamine to be more basic than dimethylamine due to the increased $+I$ effect in trimethylamine. However in aqueous solution dimethylamine is more basic according to my textbook. Can someone please explain how? Is it because of hydrogen bonding?

You might want to look at the steric effects. The proton is 'less available' in $\ce{NMe3}$ than in $\ce{NHMe2}$, and so the molecule is less basic.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44560/which-is-the-strongest-base-relative-to-ammonia
